# WSO2 Api Manager / Integrator Respond mediator verbose execution

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Is it possible to enable verbose logging for  mediator. I'm debugging some issue, and can put a  call befor  mediator, but can't put it after to verify it actually executed.

How do I make sure that  actually sent a response and what is that response?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable debug logs for the package `org.apache.synapse`. If that's too verbose, narrow the scope by either moving one level into the package hierarchy `org.apache.synapse.mediators` or to the actual class itself `org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.RespondMediator`.

Also, inorder to see what response was sent you can enable [wirelogs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/micro-integrator/classic-observability-logs/configuring-log4j2-properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs) in the server.